# Selecting top N most different items of a product

Tags: python, combinatorics

I have several sets of items (options), for example like this:

```
set1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
set2 = ['!', '@', '#', '$']
set3 = [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

and I create list of all the combinations (using `itertools.product`), which gives me something like this:

```
('a', '!', 1),
('a', '!', 2),
('a', '!', 3),
('a', '!', 4),
('a', '@', 1),
('a', '@', 2),
('a', '@', 3),
...
('d', '#', 3),
('d', '#', 4),
('d', '$', 1),
('d', '$', 2),
('d', '$', 3),
('d', '$', 4)
```

This is a simple example, I have actually more sets with more options, which result in many thousands of combinations. Now I need to select N combinations where the resulting set of combinations would conform to several properties:

1. Every option of every set must be present at least once.

- It would be nice if distribution of each option would be somewhat similar (as in "a should be in ~25% of combinations, so should b,c,e...Having 'a' in 90% combinations would be considered bad).

2. Combinations should be as distant from other combinations as possible. By distant I mean this: `('a', '!', 1)` is very  "close" to `('a', '!', 2)`, but very distant to `('d', '$', 4)`. The point is to have minimal number of same options between the two.

I'm struggling to even figure out where to start. I was thinking of serializing combinations and hashing them, hoping for somewhat equal distribution, but I don't think this would have the necessary properties I need.

Thank you

Comment: a starting point would be to _choose_ a distance to compare strings (representing the tuples). Hamming distance?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like requirement (2) already covers the bullet point under requirement (1). And if we implement (2), we should get (1) automatically so long as enough items are requested. Try this. If it doesn't do what you want, you probably need to be more specific about your situation. If it's too slow, you probably need to be more specific about the sizes of your inputs.

```
from functools import reduce

def combos(N, *iterables):
    lists = list(map(list, iterables))
    assert max(map(len, lists)) <= N <= reduce(lambda x, y: x * y, map(len, lists))
    uses = [{k: 0 for k in l} for l in lists]
    output = []
    for _ in range(N):
        new = []
        for i in range(len(lists)):
            items = [k for k, _ in
                sorted(uses[i].items(), key = lambda x: (x[1], x[0]))]
            if i == len(lists) - 1:
                # Avoid adding a duplicate list to `output`.
                items = [k for k in items if new + [k] not in output]
            new.append(items[0])
            uses[i][items[0]] += 1
        output.append(new)
    return output

print(combos(8, set1, set2, set3))
```